# How to set default value in referenceinput in react - admin

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

```
<ReferenceInput label="Department" source="DepartmentID" reference="Department">
  <SelectInput optionText="DepartmentName" />
</ReferenceInput>
```

I need to set the default value using reference input.

Comment: I have 1 collection if the collection has only one input value then I can set the default value using reference input please give some solution.

Comment: It doesn't work like this? https://marmelab.com/react-admin/CreateEdit.html#default-values

Comment: @MaxAlex, I think the link you provided does not shed any light on OP's question. The heart of the question lies on how we can access the `reference` list inside the `defaultValue` props so that you can populate the first element in the list. Regret that I do not have an answer either.

Comment: After reading through the react-admin input docs, I'm not sure this is something supported by default for ReferenceInput. Maybe you could use a FormDataConsumer? https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#linking-two-inputs

Answer (score 2):

after some research and test I made a possible solution:

```
    const SelectInputDefaultValue = ({ optionText, ...rest }) => {
        const {choices} = rest;
        let defaultChoice = choices && choices.length===1? choices[0]:""
        return (
            <SelectInput optionText={optionText} defaultValue={defaultChoice.id} {...rest}/>
    )
}
```

This one is about setting a default value if there is only one choice, but you can adapt to your needs.

The use will be as follows:

```
    <ReferenceInput
        label="Department"
        source="DepartmentID"
        reference="Department">
        <SelectInputDefaultValue optionText="DepartmentName"/>
    </ReferenceInput>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set default value by passing id which will be one of option values id. In my example, I send ID value from another form as a params.name prop to another component to set default value as one of available option

```
<ReferenceInput
        defaultValue={params && params.name}
        label="Notification Group"
        source="notification_group_id"
        reference="notification_group"
        allowEmpty

      >
        <SelectInput
          optionText="notification_group_name"
        />
</ReferenceInput>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [defaultValue](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#defaultvalue) and hardcode an id value:

```
<ReferenceInput 
  label="Department" 
  source="DepartmentID" 
  reference="Department"
  sort={{ field: 'DepartmentName', order: 'ASC'}}
  defaultValue={1}
>
   <SelectInput optionText="DepartmentName" />
</ReferenceInput>
```

Note this is the same as Nikita's [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67400057/3368818), but just wanted to show you can hardcode a value and also provide the documentation link.